# Limit amount of results using group by without affecting JSON output?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to build a threaded comments system by grouping the parent_ids together and limit the results using taken.

**Comment table**

```
$table->increments('id');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('parent_id')->index()->nullable();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('user_image')->default('http://lorempixel.com/60/60/people/');
        $table->timestamps();
```

When I don't use `take()` to limit the result the JSON outputs as expected by being `groupedBy('parent_id')`

**Query without `take()`**

```
$post->comments->groupBy('parent_id');
```

[JSON Output example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyMKpW?editors=0010)

**Query with `take()`**

```
$post->comments->take(5)->groupBy('parent_id')
```

When I use `take()` it changes the JSON output to no longer include the grouped by parent_id as keys.

[JSON Output example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zLJaEb?editors=0010)

How do I limit results without having an effect on the JSON output?

*edited*

**Post Controller**

```
public function index(Post $post)
{
   $comments = $post->comments->groupBy('parent_id');
   return $comments;
}
```

**Edit**

Why were the other replies deleted from this thread?

**Edit 2**

Oddly enough this query works based on the limit I set. So if I set the limit to a lower limit like 5 I get the grouped by keys outputting normally and JSON. However, if I set the limit by 5 I don't get those keys. See the JSON outputs above:

```
$comments = DB::table('comments')
                    ->where('post_id',1)
                    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
                    ->limit(7)
                    ->get();

return collect($comments)->groupBy('parent_id');
```

Comment: I think it's impossible with eloquent, but you can try with a query: http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/get_top_n_each_group

Comment: I think so too, but do you know how I do this a raw query?

Comment: It would really be useful to show the actual query to use instead of a link that's probably going to be dead for the next person that visits this question.

Comment: You can use DB::select ('select id, ... from ....');  you put the query there as in the link example

Comment: Any ideas what that query would look like? I got this:

`$comments = DB::table('comments')
                        ->whereRaw('post_id = 1')
                        ->groupBy('parent_id')
                        ->limit(5)
                        ->get();
`

**Error I'm getting**

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'threaded.comments.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `comments` where post_id = 1 group by `parent_id` limit 5)

Comment: That's because any column you use in a select statement must appear in the group by clause.

Comment: Please post the whole controller method.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, here ya go.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($comments);` when using `->take(5)`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir is there any specific part you want from the result of `dd($comment)`? Also here is the raw SQL being output for using take:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`post_id` = '1' and `comments`.`post_id` IS not NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the way `json_encode()` handles arrays with numeric keys.

In the case without `->take(5)`, the array keys are `[0, 1, 6, 9]`. They are not sequential and so get encoded as a JSON object.

In the case with `->take(5)`, the array keys are `[0, 1]`. These are sequential and so get encoded as a JSON array.

You can solve this by using `null` instead of `0` for parentless comments. Using `null` to represent non-existent data is also a better solution in general.

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answer?